# extract buffer mean by simulation (RasterStack)

Tags: r, extract, raster

I have two files:

- a RasterStack (where each layer represents 1 simulated map of air quality index) named m_stack;
- a SpatialPointsDataFrame (where each point represents a place of residence) named shph;

I want to extract mean air quality index of each place of residence, by simulation. To compute mean air quality index i use a small buffer (60 meters).

I am managing to extract mean air quality index for each place of residence. 
but i want one mean for each place of residence, by simulation).

Next I'll try to give a simple example:

```
# create 2 raster maps (as example of 2 air quality index simulations)
map_r1 = raster(ncol = 10, nrow = 10, xmn = 0, xmx = 100, ymn = 0, ymx = 100)
values(map_r1) = seq(1:ncell(map_r1))
map_r2 = raster(ncol = 10, nrow = 10, xmn = 0, xmx = 100, ymn = 0, ymx = 100)
values(map_r2) = 1:ncell(map_r2)*2

# create RasterStack adding both raster maps
map_stack<-stack(map_r1,map_r2)

# create SpatialPoint (as example of 3 places of residence)
x <- c(20,40,60)
y <- c(20,40,60)
v1 <- c(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)
map_p<-as.data.frame(cbind(x,y,v1))
coordinates(map_p) <- ~x + y
```

Then, to extract mean value for each place of residence, by simulation i tried the following:

```
# extract mean value (buffer=15 as example) for each point
buff<-extract(map_stack,map_p,buffer=15)
mean<-sapply(buff,mean)
```

Result only gives me one mean value for each place of residence (computes the mean of all simulations). I would be very happy to ear ideas how to extract mean air quality index for each residence, by simulation. Kind regards, Manuel

Comment: You should explain "by simulation". Do you mean something like Monte Carlo simulation? Do you want to select random observations within the 15 m buffer? Then you can probably do   s <- sapply(buff,  function(x) sample(x, 1))  and repeat that many times. However, given the small buffer size this does not seem to be a  very sensible approach.

Comment: thank you for your reply. by simulation = by layer (each layer is 1 simulation obtained with function krige).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small example that shows you how this works (taken from ?extract).

```
r <- raster(ncol=36, nrow=18)
r[] <- 1:ncell(r)
s <- stack(r, r*2, r^2)

xy <- cbind(-50, seq(-80, 80, by=20))
e <- extract(s, xy[2:3,], buffer=1000000)
e

#[[1]]
#     layer.1 layer.2 layer.3
#[1,]     517    1034  267289
#[2,]     518    1036  268324
#[3,]     552    1104  304704
#[4,]     553    1106  305809
#[5,]     554    1108  306916
#[6,]     555    1110  308025
#
#[[2]]
#     layer.1 layer.2 layer.3
#[1,]     445     890  198025
#[2,]     446     892  198916
#[3,]     481     962  231361
#[4,]     482     964  232324
```

As you can see, for each point you get a matrix with the values for each layer. You can now use sapply to compute what you want. If you want the mean by layer. You could do

```
sapply(e, colMeans)
            [,1]     [,2]
#layer.1    541.5    463.5
#layer.2   1083.0    927.0
#layer.3 293511.2 215156.5
```